# Detect Object Using Deep Learning Tool Error

Tags: arcgis-pro, image, deep-learning

I am having a problem when using the Detect Object Using Deep Learning tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.
Problem: When I add any model to the tool the following error appears always.

[image]

I downloaded many models but the same error occurs always.

> Error: Model Definition (Required) ERROR 002667 Unable to initialize
> python raster function with scalar arguments. [CAUsers\admin \AppData
> \ Local \Temp \ArcGISProTemp8080
> BuildingFootprintExtraction_Africa.dIpk\ArcGISInstanceDetector.py]
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "CAUsers\admin \AppDataocal 
> Temp \ArcGISProTemp8080
> Visa_building_footprints.dIpk\ArcGISInstanceDetector.py", line 142, in
> initialize 1{}.{}1.format(frameworlc,
> selfjson_inforModelConfiguration1)), 'ChildInstanceDetector') File "H:
> \ArcGIS\ Pro\ binWython \envAarcgispro-py3Mib\importlib \init_.py",
> line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap.Acd_import(name[level:],
> package, level) File "", line 1006, in
> _gcd_import File "", line 983, in _find_and_load File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 677, in Joad_unlocked File "",
> line 728, in exec module File "", line
> 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "H:\ArcGISNProThinWython
> \envAarcgispro-py3MibVite-packages\arcgis \ learAmodels_inferencing
> _maskrcnn_inferencing.py", line 14, in  from skimage.measure
> import find_contours ModuleNotFoundErron No module named 'skimage'
> Unable to initialize python raster function with scalar arguments.
> This parameter can be an Esri model definition JSON file (.emd), a
> JSON string, or a deep learning model package (.dlpk). A JSON string
> is useful when this tool is used on the server so you can paste the
> JSON string rather than upload the .emd file. The .dlpk file must be
> stored locally.  It contains the path to the deep learning binary
> model file, the path to the Python raster function to be used, and
> other parameters such as preferred tile size or padding.

Comment: You are working in ArcGIS Pro 2.8, so have you updated the Deep Learning Libraries?

Comment: Yes I updated it to 2.8